# Passing multiple parameters with eventcallback to the Parent component

Tags: blazor-server-side, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

I'm experiencing some issues with my eventacllback which I'm charging with multiple (at least 2) parameters. The Child component gets underlined in red, even though the whole project runs and there's no runtime issues with that. It just bugs me the errors listed in Error List window. Plus I've mentioned the Hot Reload complains about it and not working. Below are the details.

VS underlines in red the eventcallbacks

[image: 1]

As you can see from the above picture, the callback events with just one parameter are fine, it just complains when multiple are present.

The definition of the callback is like below:

`[Parameter] public EventCallback<(int, int, string)> OnRecordLevelMenuItemClick { get; set; }`

and there's nothing exceptional the way I'm invoking it:

`await OnRecordLevelMenuItemClick.InvokeAsync((buttonId, menuId??0, recordId));`

Here's how I'm handling the eventcallback in my Parent component:

```
private void RowLevelmenuItemClickHandler(int buttonId, int menuId, string recordId)
     {
          var menuOption = _menuItems.GetValueOrDefault(menuId);
    
          _snackBar?.Add($"Menu clicked. Option: {menuOption}", Severity.Info);
     }
```

As I've previously mentioned, there's no compilation errors and everything works fine. It's just not being able to use the Hot Reload that kills me.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.